# How te get the name property of a selected point in a highmap

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have a highmap and in which I can select multiple states/points. On a button click I would like to have the currently selected states outputted. My code:

```
$('#calculate-scenario').on('click', function() {

    var chart = $('#ti_map_tp').highcharts();                       
    var selectedPoints = chart.getSelectedPoints();

    alert(selectedPoints.length);

});
```

This works, but I can't figure out how to get the `name` property of the selected point. For example I tried:

`selectedPoints.Point.name`

Any help is much appreciated.

Regards, Bart

**EDIT**

```
$('#calculate-scenario').on('click', function() {
    var selectedPointsStr = '';
    var chart = $('#ti_map_tp').highcharts();                       
    var selectedPoints = chart.getSelectedPoints();
    if (selectedPoints.length == 0) {
        selectedPointsStr += '0,';
    } else {        
        $.each(selectedPoints, function(i, value) {
            selectedPointsStr += value.value + ',';
        });
    }
    selectedPointsStr = selectedPointsStr.substring(0,selectedPointsStr.length -1);
});
```

Comment: try  var selectedPoints = chart.getSelectedPoints().getName();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there could be several selected points (`getSelectedPoints()` returns an array), you either need to choose to always select the first point or some other method. Regardless, you can access the name by using the right array index: i.e. `selectedPoints[0].name`.

```
$('#button').on('click', function() {
  var chart = $('#container').highcharts();                       
  var selectedPoints = chart.getSelectedPoints();
  alert(selectedPoints[0].name);
});
```

**Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/4qrsfco5/3/**

Comment: Tnx. you got me on the right track. I edited your code a bit (see my edit in my original post) since I needed a string of all selected points